# Potential Exceptions using builtin str() type in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, exception, built-in

When working with built-in types like `int` and `float` in Python, it's common to employ exception handling in cases where input might be unreliable:

```
def friendly_int_convert(val):
    "Convert value to int or return 37 & print an alert if conversion fails"
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, that value doesn\'t work... I chose 37 for you!')
        return 37
```

Are there any prominent edge-cases to be aware of when using `str()`?

```
def friendly_str_convert(val):
    "Convert value to str or return 'yo!' & print an alert if conversion fails"
    try:
        return str(val)
    except Exception: # Some specific Exception here
        print('Sorry, that value doesn\'t work... I chose \'yo!\' for you!')
        return 'yo!'
```

I really don't like using a broad `Exception` since there are cases like `NameError` that signify a problem with the code and should raise an error. I've considered `UnicodeError` as a candidate but I'm not sure whether `str()` causes it (vs. `foo.encode()` and `foo.decode()` where it's easier to understand) and would love an example of what input, if any, would trigger it.

In summary: Is it generally safe to use `str()` without a `try` / `except` block even with unreliable input?

Comment: `Exception` isn't a base class for `KeyboardInterrupt`, which is why using `except Exception` is preferable to using a bare `except`.

Comment: @chepner that's a good point, edited to remove the reference to `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982099/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands I hadn’t considered the case of exceeding maximum recursion depth when typecasting a deeply nested object to a string. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a huge difference between `str` and `int` in this regard.  `int` can definitely raise `TypeError` and `ValueError`.

As far as I can think, the only exception that `str` can raise for normal objects is `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
>>> s = u"a\xac\u1234\u20ac\U00008000"
>>> str(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And that only happens on python2.x.

Of course, I can easily make a class that fails with just about any exception imaginable:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...   pass
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __str__(self):
...     raise MyError
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> str(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __str__
__main__.MyError
```

For the most part, I would question some of the implicit assumptions that all exceptions *need* to be handled at this point.  Generally, it's best to only handle exceptions that you *know* how to handle.  In this case, exotic exceptions that happen because the user put junk into the function should probably be handled at the level where the junk is going in -- not within the function itself.  Catching the error and returning some value which is likely nonsense isn't going to be super helpful for debugging issues, etc.

Comment: Interestingly enough, trying your example above doesn't reproduce the error on my end: `>>> str(s) ... 'a¬ሴ€耀'`! Great point with the custom exceptions.

Comment: @Alec -- I neglected to see that you're working on python3.x.  `str` is different there, but you can _might_ end up with a similar issue when encoding/decoding bytes.

Answer (score 3):

> In summary: Is it generally safe to use `str()` without a `try` / `except` block even with unreliable input?

That depends on what kind of input we're talking about. You've tagged this question Python 3, so you don't need to worry about the UnicodeEncodeErrors you'd get with Python 2 and Unicode input, but the object you're receiving could do pretty much anything in its `__str__` or `__repr__`, raising pretty much any kind of exception. For example,

```
In [18]: import weakref

In [19]: class Foo(object): pass

In [20]: str(weakref.proxy(Foo()))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReferenceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-396b2ab40052> in <module>()
----> 1 str(weakref.proxy(Foo()))

ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that Python 2 would likely involve some additional Unicode trickery. Is there a way to detect if `__str__` or `__repr__` have been modified before calling `str()`?

Comment: @Alec: Modified? No, and it wouldn't help you anyway. We don't need to modify any `__str__` methods to get crazy exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that the `weakref` case is actually a good example of your point. My objective is more to catch strange user input so hopefully I can avoid needing to handle any of these more interesting exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Due to concerns you've raised, I'd do `except Exception as e:`. `Exception` is generic "catch-all" in Python 3 for "normal" exceptions (other than "system-level" exceptions resulting from process getting signals, `KeyboardInterrupt`, etc).

If I were you I'd log the actual exception (`e` in my example above) at the very least, to see what actually happen (your code silently drops actual exception object by doing `except Exception:`).

Comment: Interesting, I'd never heard of StandardError before (it doesn't show up in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html))

Comment: [`StandardError` doesn't exist in Python 3.](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-to-exceptions)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing that out, I guess that explains why it's not in the docs :)