# Can a conversion to string raise an error?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, casting

I was wondering if converting to string i.e. `str(sth)` can raise an exception like for example `float(sth)` does? 
I am asking this to know if it is necessary to wrap my code in:

```
try:
    x = str(value)
except ValueError:
    x = None
```

to be sure that execution does not stop because of conversion failure.

Also does this differ in Python 2 and 3, since the `str` class is different in them??

Comment: Every part of you code that does 'something' can possibly go wrong what will lead to an error. ;-) But since you can't put everything in an `try except` I would also look how big is the chance that something can go wrong. If the canhce is big, put in in their own `try except` block. If chance is lower, then you might be better of putting it in a `try except` block with multiple code lines.

Comment: @Tenzin: It's not just a matter of how likely the exception is, but of what the correct behavior is when there's an exception. The OP isn't asking vaguely "hey, can something go wrong?"; rather, (s)he's asking specifically if string conversion has the concept of "this value can't be converted to a string" (`ValueError`), because if so, (s)he has a reasonable way to handle that in his/her case.

Comment: Highly nested data structure may trigger an exception due to recursion limit...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you encounter a custom class that explicitly raises an exception in `__str__` (or `__repr__` if `__str__` is not defined). Or, for example a class that returns a `bytes` object from `__str__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return b''

str(Foo()) # TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

But personally, I have *never* seen this and I'm pretty sure no one has; it would be daft to do it. Likewise, a silly mistake in the implementation of `__str__` or edge cases might create another `Exception`. It is interesting to see how you could push Python to these edge cases (look at [*@user2357112*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982099/4952130) answer here).

Other than that case, no built-ins generally raise an exception in this case since it is defined for all of them in `Py2` and `Py3`.

For user defined classes `str` will use `object.__str__` by default if not defined in Python 3 and, in Python 2, use it if a class is a new style class (inherits from `object`).

If a class is an old style class I *believe* it is `classobj.__str__` that is used for classes and `instance.__str__` for instances.

In general, I would not catch this, special cases aren't special enough for this.

Answer (score 21):

Easily. You could have a container class with a recursion-unsafe `__str__` or `__repr__` that ends up in a reference loop:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.empty([1], dtype=object)
x[0] = x
str(x)  # RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Or just a really highly nested object:

```
x = []
for i in xrange(2000):
    x = [x]

str(x)  # RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of a list
```

Heck, even with just built-in types, you could get something a lot worse than an exception:

```
x = {}
for i in range(1000000):
    x = {1: x}
str(x)  # python.exe has stopped working
        # Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
```

That's a C stack overflow, since `dict_repr` doesn't (currently) use `Py_EnterRecursiveCall`. You can't catch *that* with an `except` block!

Back to the more mundane errors, you could have a `weakref.proxy` to a dead object:

```
import weakref

class Foo(object):
    pass

str(weakref.proxy(Foo()))  # ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Or you could just write a class that raises whatever you want in `__str__` or `__repr__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        raise Exception

str(Foo())  # Raises an Exception
```

---

Specific to Python 2, you could get a case where `print`ing an object produces partial output and *then* raises an exception, even though it ostensibly should have never reached the stage of printing anything:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        raise Exception

print [Foo()]  # Prints a single opening bracket, then raises an Exception!
```

This is due to the obsolete [`tp_print`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_print) C-level hook.

You could also get a Python 2-specific `UnicodeEncodeError` when `str`-ing a `unicode` object that contains non-ASCII characters, since Python 2 `str` objects are bytestrings:

```
str(u'\u1000')  # Fails on Python 2 only
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use python2 in your examples?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Because I was thinking about adding the Python 2-specific case of `str`-ing a `unicode` object with non-ASCII characters in it, and I forgot to match my examples to the Python 3.x tag.

Answer (score 19):

In theory yes, it can, but in practice it almost certainly won't. The way that the `str` function works is it calls the `__str__` function of the object that it's converting to a string. Built in types like `List`, numeric types, and others will return values about what you would expect, `[x,y,z]` for a `List`, the number as a string for a numerical type, etc. `object` has a `__str__` method that gives an output like `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdb2fa6a640>`, which often isn't very useful but won't raise an exception.

So, calling `str` on any builtin is almost certainly not going to raise an exception (Admittedly, I can't find a guarantee for this in the Python documentation, but I can't imagine a situation where it would happen)

That said, it is [possible to override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144026/how-to-define-a-str-method-for-a-class) the `__str__` method for a custom class. If this is done, then that method could raise an exception just like any other function that a programmer could write could - an intentional exception, an uncaught `IndexError` or the like, etc. Even if you're not overriding `__str__`, if you're using a module that does, it's entirely possible the author of that module made some mistake on some rare edge that will raise an exception.

**The bottom line:** It shouldn't if everyone's done their job right, but it could. In almost any practical situation I wouldn't bother try/catching.

Comment: What if you run out of memory? That could realistically happen on long lists.

Comment: That's a good point! Yes, a `MemoryError` could occur during the `str` method, along with a `KeyboardInterrupt`, and probably a few more I'm forgetting. If someone reasonably expects either of those could happen, it may be good to catch them ([Though it's sometimes challenging to catch MemoryErrors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899910/python-not-catching-memoryerror))

Answer (score 10):

Just to add to the other answers, `str()` does not throw an exception in many (perhaps surprising) contexts, for example you can apply it to a function, a generator, or itself. However, I can't imagine a situation where you would actually want to do this in practice.

```
>>> def a(): pass
... 
>>> str(a)
'<function a at 0x7fc43614e048>'
>>> 
>>> str(x for x in range(3))
'<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc434b95f10>'
>>> 
>>> str(str())
''
>>>
```