# to overcome on Runtime Warning

Tags: pandas

C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:2323: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
values = values.astype(str)

I m running this code on AWS and it consistently showing this warning, but code is running smoothly.
I want to remove this code?
Thanks in Advance
Vaibhav B.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Also experiencing this issue when using panda.concat 
Line is

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

While I don't recommend it you can remove the error with this code

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

The issue with this is that all errors will be ignored, therefore it is not ideal.

Hopefully somebody can come forward with a proper solution!

Answer (score 0):

So `values.astype(str)` can't convert all values to `str`. What does `values` look like? Try this:

```py
for v in values:
  try:
    str(v)
  except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    print(v)
```

It's possible that Pandas hides the exact [conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982099/819417).

Answer (score -1):

I have not the answer to solve this problem, but what I can say is the problem may be related to the version of Pandas you are using.

Also I faced this problem in my project, but only when I updated the package version installed to the newest one; as you said, despite the warning the program runs without problems.

Try to install an older version of Pandas package. In the following, I leave you a link about doing this: [How to install a specific package version using pip](https://thispointer.com/install-a-specific-python-package-version-using-pip/#how-to-install-a-specific-package-version-using-pip)

Hope to have been helpful to you :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).